# Assembly x86 - Menu's colors are gone when transferring a page

Tags: assembly

so this is a part of my code:

```
start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    ;Set graphics mode 320x200 & 256 colors
     mov ax,13h
     int 10h

     mov al,00h
     mov ah,0
     int 10h
     mov ah,09h
     mov bl, 0c3h ; 3 = light blue , c = lightning (for unknown reason) & red line
     mov cx, 40   ; numbers of characters to color
     int 10h
     mov dx, offset menu    
     int 21h    
    ;set cursor location(dh,dl) (I'm hiding the cursor)
     mov dl, 16  ; column. 
     mov dh, 30  ; row. 
     mov ah, 02h
     int 10h         
     call Beep  
    jmp start
```

I added the jmp start at the end just so you guys realise that even when I jump to the start even without transferring to another page the colors are still gone and the cursor position is not set to the position I told him, yet the menu is showing, what am I doing wrong?

Note: The colors and cursor position are working before I jump to the start back again.

Comment: Your first `int 10h` call sets the graphics mode to mode 13h(320x200 & 256 colors), but your second sets it to mode `00h` which is grayscale on CGA/EGA. See [Ralf Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm#Table10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly remove the `jmp start` and replace it by `mov ah,0` and `int 16h`. This will give you a chance to actually **see** what's on screen.

```
mov ax,13h
int 10h

mov al,00h
mov ah,0
int 10h
```

In this block of code you set the screen 2 times! The 2nd and final time it's set to a 16-color text screen of 40 columns and 25 rows.

---

```
mov bl, 0c3h ; 3 = light blue , c = lightning (for unknown reason) & red line
```

You're using the BIOS 'write character and attribute' function with too few parameters. You should also define:

```
mov al, " "  ;Space character
mov bh, 0    ;Display page 0
mov bl, 0C3h ;This chooses a cyan foreground on a red background
```